# Absolute positioning and changing fixed height

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a lot of position absolute and relative to get the right layout for this project. As you can see in my fiddle the height of the black background is set to a fixed height because it won't show if i don't do this.

My question is if there's a way to set this height to just fill the window? Because with the fixed height you've got a scrollbar or whitespace which I'm trying to avoid

My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m56kd0yn/)

HTML

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=logo" alt="logo" />
  </div>
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius aspernatur nemo voluptatem provident fuga     beatae. Dolore explicabo laborum laboriosam debitis eligendi rerum quis nam facere inventore magnam eum nisi sed
  </p>
</div>
<div class="box-bg"></div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
.header img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
.header-bg {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.box p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box-bg {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  background: black;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: if im correct, set body background to black so it will fit the whole window, if not set html and body to height 100% - gues this should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a height, use the bottom position: (and change the position to absolute).

```
.box-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    background: black;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m56kd0yn/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about absolute positioning for the background, a simple solution that fits perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The CSS viewport height can be used to achieve things like this but it depends what browsers you are supporting: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Also, from the fiddle its difficult to picture what you want to achieve. Can you explain?

That black area could just be a body background colour?

Comment: Yes I found a solution by using vh for height  but it doesn't have support for some of the older browser versions.

Comment: The problem with the dark background is that it has to start somewhat in the middle of the content box. I don't think this can be solved with a solid color using background position